# Accelerometer sensor keep same settings on landscape mode as portrait

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sensors

Im using Accelerometer sensor in my app. I want the degres for the Accelerometer stays the same on landscape mode as portrait mode. Because when i have it in portrait mode the numbers is like this photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fN3.png and in landscape mode it gives this numbers https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fN3.png#1 .

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [documentatiion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) this is proper behaviour. When you phone is in portrait mode, different forces affects your sensors thenwhen phone is in landscape orientation.

There is no simple way to make those values stay the same in both mode, you cannot changes the laws of physics :)

If you really want to use those readings, either you can set fixed activity orientations (always portrait or always landscape) but still, if you rotate yoor phone, readings will change.

The second option is to check for screen orientation in runtime and thane reffer to proper sensor value.